# PostgreSQL to azuredata factory

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure-data-factory

copy data from postgreSQL db  to azure sQl db

The source is in different server and i want to move the data from source server to destination server for that i need to install self hosted integration runtime but i am unable to install that is there another way to do that.

Comment: What does "unable to install that" mean? What is the constraint? There are many ways to transfer data. You could export source data to flat files, put them on a flashdrive and post to the target server. Do you have a server with network connectivity to both databases? Do you have logins to both databases? What are your constraints?

Comment: For example if you can connect to Azure SQL from the postgreSQL server, you can push the data in

Comment: what error exactly you are facing?

Comment: Install SHIR in the server where you have access to PostgreSQL db

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the ask here , user is not willing to install Self hosted IR , but the goal is to copy data from postgressql ( in prermise ) to Azure sql . I am quite sure without  SHIR , we cannot use azure data factory in this case  .

I suggest to use pg_dump to copy the data locally and then move the local file to a cloud storage and then copy data from cloud storage to Azure SQl using  ADF .